# ZipFile to File to FileField Django Python

Tags: python, django, file, type-conversion, byte

I'm doing a call from a API that give me a zip file with two file in it.
I manage to extract the file i need (cause it's a PDF)

and now i just can't find a solution to save it in my filefield without creating the file in my pc.

```py
        with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response3.content)) as z: # response3 is my response to the API
            for target_file in z.namelist():
                if target_file.endswith('pdf'):
                    z.extract(member=target_file) # that's how i can have acces to my file and know it is a valid PDF

                    # here begin the trick
                    with io.BytesIO() as buf:
                        z.open(target_file).write(buf)
                        buf.seek(0)
                    f = File.open(buf) # File is an import of django.core.files
                    rbe, created = RBE.objects.update_or_create(file=f)
```

With this code i get an error with write of z.open(...).write as below:

```
    z.open(target_file).write(buf)
io.UnsupportedOperation: write
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with intense hardwork 2 migraine and 1 ragequit i finally manage it.

Hope it might help someone

```
        with ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response3.content), 'r') as z:
            for target_file in z.namelist():
                if target_file.endswith('pdf'):
                    with z.open(target_file) as myfile:
                        with io.BytesIO() as buf:
                            buf.write(myfile.read())
                            buf.seek(0)
                            file = File(buf, target_file) # still the File from django
                            rbe = RBE.objects.create(file=file, establishment=establishment)
```